# creating bidirectional RNN not working giving error

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train a recurrent neural network to classify handrawings using [this tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/recurrent_quickdraw.md)

however when running this code:

```
    def _add_regular_rnn_layers(convolved, lengths):
    """Adds RNN layers."""
    if params["cell_type"] == "lstm":
        cell = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell
    elif params["cell_type"] == "block_lstm":
        cell = tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.LSTMCell
    cells_fw = [cell(params["num_nodes"]) for _ in range(params["num_layers"])]
    cells_bw = [cell(params["num_nodes"]) for _ in range(params["num_layers"])]
    if params["dropout"] > 0.0:
        cells_fw = [tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell) for cell in cells_fw]
        cells_bw = [tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell) for cell in cells_bw]

    bidirectional_rnn = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
        tf.keras.layers.RNN(cells_fw, return_sequences=True),
        merge_mode='concat',
        backward_layer=tf.keras.layers.RNN(cells_bw, return_sequences=True)
    )
    outputs = bidirectional_rnn(convolved)

    return outputs
```

in particular this line:

```
bidirectional_rnn = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
```

gives this error:

`TypeError: The argument 'cell' ({'class_name': 'BasicLSTMCell', 'config': {'name': 'basic_lstm_cell_1', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': None, 'num_units': 128, 'forget_bias': 1.0, 'state_is_tuple': True, 'activation': 'tanh', 'reuse': None}}) is not an RNNCell: 'output_size' property is missing, 'state_size' property is missing, either 'zero_state' or 'get_initial_state' method is required, is not callable.`

any tips on how to fix this??

Comment: That tutorial is extremely outdated, you should just use `tf.keras.layers.LSTM`.

Comment: The error says that `'output_size' property is missing, 'state_size' property is missing, either 'zero_state' or 'get_initial_state' method is required, is not callable.`